# I want to change background image by time of day

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change background image during particular part of day using JavaScript. So, i want from 6:00 to 20:00 daytime pic and from 20-06 night time pic. I am learning JS last couple of months so i m quite new to this.I created clock also.

I tried last days by Google it, still nothing, no solution. Please help.

My html :

```
<div class="banner">

<div class="image-day" id="img-day"></div>        
<div class="image-night" id="img-night"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.banner {
   min-height: 100vh;
   position: relative;
   display: grid;
   place-items: center;
   text-align: center;
  }


.image-day {
   position: absolute;
   background: url(../images/bluesky.jpg)no-repeat center center/cover;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   
   
}



.image-night {
   position: absolute;
   background: url(../images/nightime.jpg)no-repeat center center/cover;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   }
```

JS clock :

```
setInterval(displayClock, 500)


function displayClock() {
   var time = new Date();

   var hrs = time.getHours();
   var min = time.getMinutes();
   var sec = time.getSeconds();

   if (hrs > 12) {
       hrs = hrs + 0;
   }


   if (hrs == 0) {
       hrs = 12;
   }


   if(hrs < 10) {
       hrs = '0' + hrs;
   }

   if (min < 10) {
       min = '0' + min;
   }

   if (sec < 10) {
       sec = '0' + sec;
   }

   document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = hrs + ':' + min + ':' + sec;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change css properties of a dom element by using the style property like :

```
<DOM element>.style.<css property> = <value>
```

In your case to change the background image you may use something like this :

```
document.querySelector(".banner").style.backgroundImage="url('../images/nightime.jpg')"
```

Since the display clock method is already running every 5 seconds you may add the following to check if hour is greater than 6 and less than 20

```
if(time.getHours()>=6&&time.getHours()<20)
    {
      document.querySelector(".banner").style.backgroundImage="url('../images/bluesky.jpg')";
    }else{
      document.querySelector(".banner").style.backgroundImage="url('../images/nightime.jpg')"
    }
```

Find a demo in this bin : [demo](https://jsbin.com/kamuhiwase/edit?html,css,js,output) . Open the demo and try changing your system time

Comment: It is working with links from demo https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png' but its not working with my images of bluesky.jpg and nighttime.jpg? What seems to be problem?